# JAX-RS URL handled so far

Tags: java, jax-rs

Is there any way to get the URL of the resource which is currently handled? Suppose I'm in Parent class (I also have grand-parent handler, parent-handler, child handler). And the full URL looks like this: /smt1/smt2/smt3/parent/child.

I know that there is a way to get the full request URL.

But is there any way to obtain /smt1/smt2/smt3/parent part in Parent handler?

Answer (score 0):

[`UriInfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html) is the class you're looking for. To get your current URL/URI you use:

```
@Context
private UriInfo info
@Path("/a/b/c")
@GET
public String get() {
  return "URL is: " + this.info.getRequestUri();
}
```